# UNIX command line file edit functionality

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

Back again with another question.

The file I have right now is of the following format:

```
1234,
1234,
1-23-4
```

I would like to do two things with this file.

First, remove the `-` characters in the third line. Therefore, `1-23-4` ==> `1234`.

Second, I would like to make it all print in one line.

The final result should look like:

```
1234,1234,1234
```

Is this possible using line commands in a script? Kindly advise.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tr`:

```
$ tr -d '\n-' < a | sed 's/$/\n/'
1234,1234,1234
```

To remove the hyphens:

```
$ tr -d '-' < file
1234,
1234,
1234
```

And the same applies for the new lines with `\n`.

As we are removing all new lines, it will miss the finishing one. To recover it, we use `sed`.

```
$prompt tr -d '\n-' < a
1234,1234,1234$prompt

$ tr -d '\n-' < a | sed 's/$/\n/'
1234,1234,1234
```

---

> Thanks fedorqui.I tried this. I replaced file with my file name but it
>   is not creating a new file with the final format for me. Sorry i think
>   I should have mentioned this in the question. My bad.

No problem. You just need to redirect it:

```
$ tr -d '\n-' < a | sed 's/$/\n/' > new_file
$ cat new_file 
1234,1234,1234
```

Comment: +1, though you _may_ need to put a finishing newline back on.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui.I tried this. I replaced file with my file name but it is not creating a new file with the final format for me. Sorry i think I should have mentioned this in the question. My bad.

Comment: Yes, that is true @paxdiablo I updated with `sed` writing it back. By the way, congrats for being 300K, that's so big :)

Comment: @Manus no problem, check my update in which I redirect the output. Hope it is clear

Comment: Hi fedorqui. Really appreciate your help. But I am stuck again. In my new file, only the last 1234 is appearing, with the '-' removed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh sorry...just opened the file in VIM

Comment: it shows some character ^M between the numbers. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: I guess this is because the original file had them, @Manus. Use `dos2unix` as described in http://linuxdemon.blogspot.nl/2011/04/how-to-remove-control-m-characters-in.html

Answer (score 1):

`tr` was a good one.

Anotherway in perl:

```
perl -pne 's/[-\n]//g' your_file
```

- `-n`-> this will act as a while loop for each line in the file.
- `-e`-> the thing after this is nothing but the expression which will act on each an every line.
- `-p`-> print each line after the expression is executed on each line.

  s/search/replace/g
- `s/` search for either a newline or "-"/ replace with empty character/g-for all occurences in the line.

Comment: Thank you Vijay. But I do not know how to use PERL. Will keep in mind when I learn the language.

Comment: I will expalin you a bit to be more comfortable for you.

Comment: @Vijay I just formatted your answer a little bit to list all the options. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

(gnu) awk:

```
awk -v RS="\0" 'gsub(/[\n-]/,"")' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "1234,
1234,
1-23-4"|awk -v RS="\0" 'gsub(/[\n-]/,"")'
1234,1234,1234
```

Comment: Thank you kent. I will try out this option and update the thread. @fedorqui's solution worked for me and Im sure this one will too.